# SAML2 SP EntityID

Tags: saml-2.0

I have some clients that use SAML IDP providers like Okta and Centrify. I just implemented SAML, and I want to know what information should I send to them when they are asking for EntityID. My SP consume url is like app.mycompany.com/saml/consume, I think the EntityID could be the same as the consume URL. My question is if I should send diferent EntityID for each customer. For example for client A something like clientA.app.mycompany.com/saml/consume, for company B something like clientB.app.mycompany.com/saml/comsume.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to send them is the EntityID for your SAML Service Provider. Depending what you have used to implement this, it can be obtained in different ways. If yo have a of the shelf software you usually export a metadatafile where the ID is located inside. If you built it yourself, it depends. This is the ID that you give in the issuer field when you send messages to the IDP.